# Jquery: unresponsive select field after clone and modification in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

As I already found the answers to several questions here, I'm sure that someone has the answer to the following question.

I've programmed an update of a select box via Ajax. Everything works fine in Internet Explorer 8+, Opera and Firefox. But when I select Internet Explorer 7 or Quirks in the Development Tools (F12), it doesn't work right. I have 3 Select fields in a row; the last two are filled after the first one is selected. This works.

Now the Problem: The complete row is cloned and added afterwards in order to allow multiple selection. For the FIRST row it works, but afterwards it doesn't.

If the second and third select should be updated, it only updates the first OPTION entry, and the select field seems to have a bug, as it does not pulldown.....  I already checked whether the problematic Pulldowns have the right HTML Content and the HTML Content I get with `jquery $().html()` is exactly the one that I want after the function updates the select field.

```
<div id="diagrammpreview" style="height:500px;width:500px;"></div>
<div id="d1">
<div id="diagramm1">
<select size="1" class="overviewtables" name="overviewtables"><option value="error">Bitte auswaehlen</option></select>
<select size="1" class="axis" name="axis1"><option value="error">Zuerst Tabelle auswaehlen</option></select>
<select size="1" class="axis" name="axis2"><option value="error">Zuerst Tabelle auswaehlen</option></select>
<input type="button" id="preview1" class="preview" name="preview1" value="Preview">
</div>
```

This is the part that is cloned:

```
$('#adddiagramm').click(function(){$('#d1').children().last().after($('#diagramm1').clone())


function fillpulldown(val,text,j_pulldown,a)
{
 var newcontent="<option value=\"error\">"+"Bitte auswaehlen"+"</option>";
 for(i=0;i<=(val.length-1);i++)
 {

 if(val[i]=="timestamp"){}
     else
     {
        newcontent=newcontent+ "<option value=\""+val[i]+"\">"+text[i]+"</option>";
     }
 }
    alert(newcontent);
 j_pulldown.html(newcontent);
 alert(j_pulldown.parent().html());
 alert(j.pulldown.html());
}
```

This function fills the pulldown menues. It works, but IE7 doesn't seem to parse the `j_pulldown.html(newcontent)` part right. The problem is only with the CLONED content.

Comment: please show your code, it will help us so we can help you

Comment: one problem I see is that you are cloning an element with an id and not changing the id on the new element. Element ids must be unique.

Comment: Tried it without using the id. But this isn't the problem i think. At: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/modifying-cloned-select-box-makes-it-unresponsive-in-ie I found someone who describes the same problem. Maybe this will help to fix the problem....

Comment: http://st-on-it.blogspot.de/2010/10/cloned-select-elements-in-ie.html this is a workaround, hope it exists another solution :(

Comment: What about using `.append()` to add the option to the select? You could use `.empty()` if you want to clear it first. I'm thinking maybe the problem IE has is with the html being changed

Comment: Solved Problem with a prototype div which is hidden; clone function do it yourself ;)